# Flutter error: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.Required by:project :geolocator_android

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get the Android app bundle .aab so I decided to open the Android module in Android Studio but to my surprise, I got the error

```
    No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4' but:
              - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                  - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
```

before the project even finished loading. Below is what my `android/build.gradle` looks like:

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    
    
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    
        }
    
    
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

And my `app/build.gradle` is as below:

```
    plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    android {
        namespace "app name"
        compileSdkVersion 34
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "ae.hobber.hobbers"
              minSdkVersion 21
            //noinspection OldTargetApi
            multiDexEnabled true
            targetSdkVersion 34
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                shrinkResources false
                minifyEnabled false
                crunchPngs false // or true
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                /*signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                keyAlias 'your_key_alias'
                keyPassword 'your_key_password'
                storeFile file('path/to/your/keystore.jks')
                storePassword 'your_keystore_password'*/
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')
    
    }
```

I tried to search for a solution across all platforms but couldn't the only one I didn't know how to come about someone saying: 'The error suggests that the Android Gradle plugin version 7.4.2 is declaring an API compatible with Java 11, while your project expects a runtime compatible with Java 8.' Which I am not sure how to solve this error with the above suggest.